# How to loop stata file and save file as .csv by using R looping function

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to open many .dta file (tax_1, tax_2, tax_3, ... tax_800), then do the task on each file (this task does not affect the looping function) and save the result as .csv file based on name of dta files:

Firstly, I open the files

```
setwd("")
list.tax <- read.dta13("tax_1.dta")
taxcode <- list.tax$ma_thue
```

And then, I do some tasks in between open and save files, as follow

```
url <- "https://example/example1"
link <- c(taxcode) %>% str_c(url, ., "/")
x<- map_dfr(link, scraper)
x.link <- x$link
info <- map(x.link,
            \(url) {
              html <- read_html(url)
              info <- html_element(html, ".company-info .description") %>% html_text2()
              # each cell in the 2-column table
              html_elements(html, ".mt-20 .responsive-table-cell") %>% 
                html_text2() %>% 
                # as 2-coumn matrix, same shape and structure as table
                matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
                # add infor row to matrix
                rbind(c("info", info))
            })  %>%
  # m[,1] - description column 
  # m[,2] - value column
  # make safe column names from 2nd column, apply those to values vector
  # map_dfr turns each such list into tibble row retunrs single tribble
  map_dfr(\(m) set_names(m[,2], make_clean_names(m[,1])))
```

Finally, I will save this task result by name of stata files:

```
write_excel_csv(data.frame(info), "tax_1.csv")
```

In do-files stata, I can loop the sequence {1,2,...,800} (forval i in 1/800} and open the file such as `list.tax <- read.dta13("tax_`i'.dta")`. I'm not very familiar with R so I'm really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Searching [r] for bulk file import will turn up a number of related answers, probably helpful with only minor changes like file name slug or similar: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+bulk+file+import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't operate like Stata in that way.  The equivalent of

```
tax_`i'.dta
```

in R is:

```
paste0("tax_", i, ".dta")
```

For example:

```r
for(i in 1:800){
  in_name <- paste0("tax_", i, ".dta")
  out_name <- paste0("tax_", i, ".csv") 
  list.tax <- read.dta13(in_name)
  << do some stuff >> 
  write_excel_csv(data.frame(info), out_name)
}
```